# Get every hour for a time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So what I am trying to is generate all the hours that are inside a specific time range.

So given the range 11 AM to 2:00 PM, I would get:

```
 11:00 AM
 12:00 PM
 1:00 PM
 2:00 PM
```

I am trying to avoid having to store every specific hour a store might be open and just store the range (I need to compare the hours against other times)

Thanks

Comment: Just store the `OpenTime` and the `ClosedTime` in the db, and do your comparisons in code ?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) (click the link to create one if you don't)...

```
create table test(
    startTime time
,   endTime time
)

insert into test
select '11:00', '14:00'

select
    dateadd(hh, n.n, t.startTime) as times
from test t
  inner join Numbers n
    -- assuming your numbers start at 1 rather than 0
    on n.n-1 <= datediff(hh, t.startTime, t.endTime)
```

If this is specialized, you can create an hours table with just 24 values.

```
create table HoursInADay(
    [hours] time not null
,   constraint PK_HoursInADay primary key ([hours])
)

-- insert
insert into HoursInADay select '1:00'
insert into HoursInADay select '2:00'
insert into HoursInADay select '3:00'
insert into HoursInADay select '4:00'
insert into HoursInADay select '5:00'
insert into HoursInADay select '6:00'
insert into HoursInADay select '7:00'
...

select
    h.[hours]
from test t
  inner join HoursInADay h
    on h.[hours] between t.startTime and t.endTime
```

Comment: @David It's slightly different.  My original answer also said to create the hours table as an option but I did not include an example to show how it would work.  Apologies if it seems I stole your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry. It looked like you created you answer, then after seeing my answer, you changed your mind and put my answer also. I apologize.

Answer (score 13):

No loops, recursive CTEs or numbers table required.

```
DECLARE 
  @start TIME(0) = '11:00 AM', 
  @end   TIME(0) =  '2:00 PM';

WITH x(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @start, @end) + 1) 
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT t = DATEADD(HOUR, n-1, @start) FROM x ORDER BY t;
```

Comment: I always feel slimy using sys tables in this way.  It feels a little hackish.

Comment: @Zhenny Well, I prefer a `Numbers` table personally, but until one ships with SQL Server, try and convince everyone to create one. [Please vote and comment, maybe we'll get one in the next version](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/258733/add-a-built-in-table-of-numbers)!

Comment: Is there a way this solution could be modified to account for a day change? For instance if you wanted each hour between 11pm Monday to 2am Tuesday

Answer (score 7):

You could use a recursive CTE.  This would generate the hours between 11 and 14:

```
;with   Hours as
        (
        select  11 as hr
        union all
        select  hr + 1
        from    Hours
        where   hr < 14
        )
select  *
from    Hours
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1658/0)

Comment: I like it the best, but it returns a int and not a time, but I'm sure I can modify to work with a time

Comment: @AaronBertrand:  yeah, i meant int and time, i edited my comment.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is to have only 1 permanent table with a list of all hours; 24 entries total.

```
Create table dbo.Hours (Hourly_Time Time NOT NULL)
Insert into dbo.Hours ...
```

Then, given times A & B:

```
select * from dbo.Hours where Hourly_Time<=A and Hourly_Time>=B
```

Comment: I like this idea, I will give this a shot.

Comment: I know what they mean; did you try the syntax you actually posted? `IF 1=<2 PRINT 'um';` yields `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

Comment: @DavidManheim please look ***REALLY CLOSELY*** at the code you posted. `=<` is ***NOT*** the same as `<=`!

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for the catch. (It's fixed. I removed my previous comments.)

Answer (score 0):

@Andomar Thanks a lot, you helped me, there is my add above your code.

```
*----------------------------

create view vw_hoursalot as 
  with Hours as
  (
      select DATEADD(
        dd, 0, DATEDIFF(
              dd, 0, DATEADD (
                    year , -5 , getDate() 
                  )
            )
      ) as dtHr
    union all
      select DATEADD (minute , 30 , dtHr ) 
        from Hours
        where dtHr < DATEADD(
            dd, 0, DATEDIFF(
                  dd, 0, DATEADD (
                        year , +5 , getDate() 
                      )
                )
        )
  )  
  select * from Hours
----------------------------  
select * from vw_hoursalot option (maxrecursion 0)
----------------------------*
```