# T-SQL to create one data point for each hour over past 24 hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

Please how may we do this:

1) Generate 24 rows one for each hour from current time back 24 hours

2) Aggregate data from another table over the past 24 hours into these 24 data points.

I have seen solutions suggesting number tables from 0-23, but these might make it difficult if we need this to start from NOW, then run back 24 hours [Get every hour for a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986344/get-every-hour-for-a-time-range)

e.g [5:00am, 4:00am, 3:00am ... 12:am, 11pm ... 7:00am,6:00am]

Source Table:

```
select d,h,count(1)cnt from msgs 
where dt>= DateAdd(hh, -24, sysdatetime()) 
group by d,h order by 1 desc,2 desc
```

Sample Data

```
d           h   cnt
2015-06-05  16  11
2015-06-05  13  44
2015-06-05  12  16
2015-06-05  11  31
2015-06-05  10  10
2015-06-05  9   12
2015-06-05  8   1
2015-06-04  21  1
2015-06-04  20  2
2015-06-04  18  5
2015-06-04  16  2
```

I have missing hours, i would need a query that fills out the missing hours with 0

Comment: What's the problem with numbers table? You're using the numbers with dateadd and getdate()?

Comment: @JamesZ i don't understand your comment?

Comment: Something like "select dateadd(hour, -1 * numbercolumn, getdate()) from numbertable" and then take the date and hour from that and number 0 (or you could of course have negative numbers)

Comment: You could use SUM instead of count, eg SUM(case when EXISTS(something) or Colx is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath you mean to use a case for each hour... that might just work, but it will give me columns, not rows...

Comment: @JamesZ let me try your suggestion

Comment: @CharlesO No, it should return all the hours with a SUM of 0

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks, your suggestion works

Comment: Please note that "create 24 data points for each hour over past 24 hours" doesn't mean what the rest of your question say. Creating 24 data points for each hour means 24 data points per hour, meaning that 24 hours * 24 data points is 576 data points for the past day. "Create one data point for each hour over past 24 hours" matches the rest of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you could use this query to provide all 24 hour ranges. Then simply aggregate and sum these values against your original query to return only 24 rows.

```
;WITH hrs AS
(
    SELECT h = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h + 1
    FROM hrs
    WHERE h + 1 <= 24
)
SELECT 
    d = left(convert(varchar(50),DateAdd(hour, -1 * h, getdate()), 21),10), 
    h = DatePart(hour, DateAdd(hour, -1 * h, getdate())), 
    cnt = 0
FROM hrs
```

Comment: You're promoting dangerous habits IMHO. Please see [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: Care to succinctly elaborate?

Comment: Did you see the clicky things in my comment? Did you read them? Oh, I see, the same m.o. Basically, converting to varchar without length is dangerous because sometimes you'll get silent truncation (= data loss) at 1 character or 30 characters, depending on the scenario. The other is that using lazy shorthand like `hh` leads people to unpredictable results when they mimic that for `y` or `w`, which don't do what most people expect (I fool entire rooms with a quiz on this in my bad habits talk). It takes 4 extra nanoseconds to type `HOUR` instead of `hh` and is much clearer and self-documenting.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there any version of MSSQL in which the code as written will fail?

Comment: It's not about the code you wrote. It's about people using those patterns in other code, where it **will** break. Have you read the blog posts yet?

Comment: After reading the blog posts I see your perspective.  Makes logical sense now: explicit and readable == better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try joining to this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_Last24Hrs
(
    @start DateTime2(7)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (d char(10), h int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @current DateTime2(7) = @start

    WHILE (@current > DateAdd(hour, -24, @start))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Result
        VALUES
        (
            REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), @current, 102) , '.', '-'),
            DATEPART(hour, @current)
        )

        SET @current = DateAdd(hour, -1, @current)
    END

    RETURN;
END;
GO

SELECT * FROM ufn_Last24Hrs(SYSDATETIME());

SELECT 
    d,h,COUNT(1)cnt 
FROM 
    ufn_Last24Hrs(SYSDATETIME()) hrs
    left join msgs 
        ON msgs.d = hrs.d
        and msgs.h = hrs.h
WHERE dt>= DateAdd(hour, -24, SYSDATETIME()) 
GROUP BY d,h 
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DES
```

Comment: I have Gone for the suggestion from JamesZ. I guess a reusable number table can indeed be applied with a little trickery