# How would I insert a record for every hour in a day in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert a record for every hour in a day.

My table structure is along the lines of

```
DATETIME            | VALUE
2016-02-01 00:00:00 | 500
2016-02-01 01:00:00 | 600
```

Assuming that I wanted to insert a record for every hour in the 1st of February 2016, my initial approach would have been something along the lines of:

```
WHILE @theTime != '2016-02-02 00:00:00'
...INSERT(blah blah blah)
//increment the @theTime variable
```

Where I'm struggling at the moment is I'm not sure how to increment the time. When I use the following code:

```
declare @theTime datetime = '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
declare @counter int = 1
declare increment cursor FOR SELECT DATEADD(hh, @counter, @theTime);

WHILE @theTime != '2016-02-02 00:00:00'

BEGIN
   PRINT @allocTime
   SET @counter = @counter + 1 
   OPEN increment
   FETCH NEXT FROM increment INTO @theTime
   CLOSE increment;
   PRINT @counter
END
```

I get this:

```
Feb  1 2016 12:00AM
2
Feb  1 2016  1:00AM
3
Feb  1 2016  1:00AM
4....
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a SQL Job?

Comment: Have a look at [Get every hour for a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986344/get-every-hour-for-a-time-range)

Comment: You are thinking of it like a programming language. Use joins. Trust me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neat trick is to use the table `master..spt_values` (of type `P`) as a seed to just get a sequence of numbers, and use `DATEADD` to add 0-23 hours to the start position:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
SELECT TOP 24 DATEADD(hour,number,@Start) AS HR
FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P'
```

This can be turned into an `INSERT` easily enough

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = '2016-02-01 00:00:00'
INSERT INTO MyTable(DateTime,value)
SELECT TOP 24 DATEADD(hour,number,@Start) AS HR, 0
FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P'
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to build a time table.  This is a table that contains 1 record for each time period you wish to add.  This approach allows you to avoid looping, which isn't one of SQLs strengths (by design).

**Example**

```
/* Returns one record for each hour between the 
 * start and end times.
 */
WITH Calendar AS
    (
        /* CTE using recursion to return a simple 
         * date table.
         */
            -- Anchor Part.
            SELECT
                @StartTime AS [DateTime]

        UNION ALL

            -- Recursive part. 
            SELECT
                DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [DateTime]) AS [DateTime]
            FROM
                Calendar
            WHERE
                [DateTime] < @EndTime
    )
SELECT
    [DateTime]
FROM
    Calendar
;
```

Now you have all the records you need you can change from a SELECT to an INSERT statement.

**Example**

```
-- Pseudocode, will not run.    
INSERT INTO [Target-Table]
    (
        [Column-A],
        ...,
        [DateTime]
FROM
    Calendar
;
```