# Generate variable time steps

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-synapse

Hello to the community.

I am trying to write a stored procedure that would fill a dimension table with time clusters in minutes. e.g. cluster = 30: 00:00-00:29, 00:30-00:59, 01:00-01:29, and so on.

So far I could not think of a better solution but to loop over 24 hours with the provided step, there is a danger of an infinite loop when the time jumps over 00:00 and starts over again.

Searching for a possible solution, I found an elegant one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10986763/12197757 but did not figure out how to adapt it to different time steps.

*EDIT: as I am working on the Azure Synapse SQL pool, sequence generation and recursive CTEs cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Squirrel point on Tally tables as an elegant and performant replacement for loops. I came with the following solution:

```
declare @st time(0) = '00:00',
        @en time(0) = '23:59',
        @incr tinyint = 7; --variable increment in minutes
 
with tally (n) as
(
  SELECT TOP 1439 --max amount of minutes from 00:00 to 23:59
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [N]
  FROM dbo.syscolumns tb1
      CROSS JOIN dbo.syscolumns tb2
)
SELECT  
          dateadd(minute, (n -1 ) * @incr, @st) as StartTime
        , CASE 
            WHEN dateadd(minute, (n - 1) * @incr, @st) < dateadd(minute, n * @incr, @st) THEN dateadd(minute, n * @incr, @st)
            ELSE CONVERT(time(0), '23:59:59')   
          END AS EndTime --Preventing time to jump over 00:00 again 
FROM    tally
where   n-1   <= datediff(minute, @st, @en) / @incr
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a recursive cte

```
; with rcte as
(
    select  tm = cast('00:00' as time(0))    -- start time
    union all
    select  tm = dateadd(minute, 30, tm)     -- 30 mins increment
    from    rcte
    where   tm  < '12:00'                    -- end time
)
select  *
from    rcte
```

The tally table approach

```
declare @st time(0) = '00:00',
        @en time(0) = '03:30';
 
with tally (n) as
(
    -- 1000 rows
    select row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1
    from (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    cross join (values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
SELECT  tm = dateadd(minute, n * 30, @st)
FROM    tally
where   n   <= datediff(minute, @st, @en) / 30
```

Comment: unfortunately, recursive CTEs are not supported in Synapse Dedicated pools :(

Comment: Added alternative using tally table (cross join). Use a permanent tally table if you have one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I could not get your code with the Tally table to work getting 'Parse error at line: 8, column: 10: Incorrect syntax near '('.' error. Did some reading about Tally tables though and came up with a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TimeCluster    TABLE 
    (
            TimeBegin   time
        ,   TimeEnd     time
    )
;
DECLARE @TimeBegin      time    =   '00:00'
    ,   @TimeEnd        time    =   '00:29'
    ,   @TimeLapseMins  int     =   30
;
WHILE   @TimeEnd <> '23:59'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TimeCluster    VALUES  (@TimeBegin, @TimeEnd)

        SET @TimeBegin  =   DATEADD(MINUTE, @TimeLapseMins, @TimeBegin  )
        SET @TimeEnd    =   DATEADD(MINUTE, @TimeLapseMins, @TimeEnd    )
        ;
    END
;

SELECT * FROM @TimeCluster
```