# What does "t=" do in SELECT t = DATEADD(HOUR, n-1, @start) FROM x ORDER BY t;

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've found this article [Get every hour for a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986344/get-every-hour-for-a-time-range) that help me a lot with this code:

```
DECLARE 
@start TIME(0) = '11:00 AM', 
@end   TIME(0) =  '2:00 PM';

WITH x(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @start, @end) + 1) 
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT t = DATEADD(HOUR, n-1, @start) FROM x ORDER BY t;
```

But I don't know what 't =' is or does in this select clause.
The same for 'rn = '

What is that? There is a technical name for that? How can I use it?

Comment: It's SQL Server dialect quirk. `SELECT col = <expression> FROM mytable` is a non-standard way of expressing `SELECT <expression> as col FROM mytable`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16     In this page you see select statement

Answer (score 1):

it sets alias name to field result

```
SELECT OriginalColumnName as MyFavorityName
FROM MyTableName
```

it is equal

```
SELECT MyFavorityName = OriginalColumnName
FROM MyTableName
```